# Regular expression to find and add characters in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Okay, I have zero knowledge of regular expressions so if someone can direct me to a better way to figure this out then by all means please do.

I figured out that a series of files are missing a particular naming convention for the database they will write to. So some might be `dbname1`, `dbname2`, `dbname3`, `abcdbname4`, `abcdbname5` and they all need to have that `abc` in the beginning. I want to write a regular expression that will find all `<name>` tags in the file that do not follow immediately by `abc` and add in `abc`. Any ideas how I can do this?

Again, forgive me if this is poorly worded/expressed. I really have absolutely zero knowledge of regular expressions.

Comment: I can't find any questions that are asking this. I know that there are questions asking how to add strings to lines but not how to add only to lines that are missing the string when some already have it.

Comment: How do these strings appear? Each on it's own line (and at the beginning of the line?)?

Comment: <Name>dbname1</Name>

and each is one the same line of each file and at the beginning of the line. I know I can use the find in files to replace all across the board.

Comment: Try find and replace, with regex mode selected. Find `<Name>(?!abc)` and replace all with  `<Name>abc`.

Comment: What if I have a couple of time name tags are used, can I use find and replace for a specific line in the file?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, exactly, but you can highlight the line and then when you do find and replace, you can check "in selection".

Comment: Sorry, I meant a couple of times that <name> are used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand properly from the comments, you have some instances of `<Name>foo` and some instances of `<name>foo` (lower-case `n`), and want to prepend `abc` to all `foo` that don't already begin with `abc`.

One way to do this is to Find and Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>), select regular expression mode, and enter:

`<[Nn]ame>(?!abc)` as the "Find what" pattern, and
`<Name>abc` as the "Replace with" pattern.

Note this will replace all matched `n` with `N`.

If you want to maintain lower case `n` in the matched instances, you can find `<([Nn])ame>(?!abc)`, and replace with `<\1ame>abc`.

Of course, you could have probably done this with two or three normal (non-regex) find and replace... firstly replacing `<Name>` with `<Name>abc`, and then replacing `abcabc` with `abc`.